# SQL Help with distinct and order by date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-order-by, distinct

The following works well but i want to have the distinct option in it as well

```
select  convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) 
from o_course
order by  convert(datetime, datestart, 103) desc
```

but if i change it to

```
select  distinct convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) 
from o_course
order by  convert(datetime, datestart, 103) desc
```

I get

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

My goal is to get all distinct dates from a datetime field and sort them descending.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the DISTINCT from the sort like this.

```
select 
    convert(nvarchar(10), foo.datestart, 103) 
from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT datestart FROM o_course) foo
order by 
    foo.datestart DESC
```

Comment: @wizzykidd: please note the FAQs about voting and accepting answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work If this answer is best for you, please accept this with the tick on the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY instead of distinct.

```
select convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) 
from o_course
group by convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) 
order by convert(datetime, datestart, 103) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what is wrong. This is one way to fix it:

```
select  distinct convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) 
from o_course
order by  convert(nvarchar(10), datestart, 103) desc
```

Comment: This will fix the error message but give wrong data. It will sort on the dd/mm/yyyy string not the underlying date

Comment: Thanks oded, however it is not sorting the results in a descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
select somedate from (select  distinct convert(nvarchar(10),datestart,103) as somedate  
from o_course) t order by somedate desc
```

Comment: This will sort on the dd/mm/yyyy string not the underlying date